# only first gpu is allocated (eventhough I make other gpus visible, in pytorch cuda framework)

Tags: python, cuda, pytorch, gpu

I am using cuda in pytorch framwework in linux server with multiple cuda devices.

The problem is that
eventhough I specified certain gpus that can be shown,
the program keeps using **only first** gpu.

(But other program works fine and other specified gpus are allocated well.
because of that, I think it is not nvidia or system problem.
nvidia-smi shows all gpus well and there's no problem.
I didn't have problem with allocating gpus with below codes before (except when the system is not working)
)

```
os.environ["CUDA_DEVICE_ORDER"]="PCI_BUS_ID"
os.environ["CUDA_VISIBILE_DEVICES"] = str(args.gpu)
```

I wrote that before running main function.
and it works fine for other programs in same system.

I printed that args.gpu variable, and could see that the value is not "0".

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried something like this?

```
device = torch.device("cuda:0,1" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu") ## specify the GPU id's, GPU id's start from 0.

model = CreateModel()

model= nn.DataParallel(model,device_ids = [0, 1])
model.to(device)
```

let me know about this

Comment: thank you for answering! 
yes it works.
but do you know what is the difference? 
I usually used that code( os.environ) and there was no problem with using [ object ].cuda() when allocating it to the specified gpu.

I cannot figure out what makes it work and not work.

Comment: `os.environ["CUDA_VISIBILE_DEVICES"] = str(args.gpu)` works in tensorflow and keras based code, but in pytorch its slightly different

Comment: I see.... so the answer is ....it doesn't work well in pytorch framework.  
it worked well in other many other programs in pytorch framework.
haha I want to know what makes it work and not work.  but yes thank you for answering to the question! 
okay I guess to mark it as correct answer is to vote? I did it

Comment: what i wanted to say is,In pytoch, `os.environ["CUDA_VISIBILE_DEVICES"] = str(args.gpu)` this will only work for single gpu, not multi gpu

Comment: Oh really? I am still curious because it worked fine with multi gpu too l
for example,  os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"]="4,5,6,7"

but I really thank you for answering to questions!

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home2/coremax/Documents/doctr/references/recognition/single_lan_pyto.py", line 38, in <module>
    device = torch.device("cuda:0,1" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")
RuntimeError: Invalid device string: 'cuda:0,1'